# Get image coordinates of lx, rx, ty, by from canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, coordinates

I am trying to create a drag and drop image within a pdf document,
get the coordinates and later on use these coordinates to sign a document.

I have a scenario just as in the picture below:

[Sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9xuF.png)

Now I need to get the coordinates of `left x` `right x` `top y` `bottom y` ( `lx rx ty by`  ) and convert them to PDF points.

So far I have tried as below:

```
          const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

          const x = e.client.x - rect.left;
          const y = e.client.y - rect.top;

          const ptX = x * 0.75;
          const ptY = y * 0.75;
          
          this.coordinates = { x: ptX, y: ptY };
```

however this only get the `lx` and `ty` how I can get the `rx` and `by`

I am using interact.js as a library for drag and drop and have created this stackblitz as a sample what I am doing

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ekxpyh?file=src/app/interact.service.ts

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what the `client` object is here, but if its a DOMRect or something of the like

```
const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

const left_x = e.client.left - rect.left;
const top_y = e.client.top - rect.top;
const right_x = e.client.right - rect.left;
const bottom_y = e.client.bottom - rect.top;
```

or even

```
const right_x = left_x + e.client.width;
const bottom_y = top_y + e.client.height;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added a stackblitz and some more description to my question regarding what is the client in this case.

The client is the event that is coming from interact.js I think its the position of the mouse